# how to create a chaine of symbolic links in c

Tags: c

when i try to execute this code i "segmentation fault"appears on the screen. Can someone please tell me what the error is? thanks in advance

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int fd , i;
    int count= atoi(argv[2]);
    char name[50];
    char nname[50];
    strcpy(nname, "./lfille");
    strcpy(name, argv[1]);
    struct stat statbuf;
/*  if((fd=open(argv[1], O_RDWR)==-1)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Datei existiert nicht\n");
    }else*/ if((lstat(argv[1], &statbuf)==-1)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error bei lstat\n");
    }else if(!(S_ISREG(statbuf.st_mode))){
        printf("%s ist nicht REG\n ", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }else{
        for(i=0; i<count; i++){
            printf("%s", nname);
            symlink(name, nname);
            sprintf(name,"%s", nname);
            sprintf(nname, "./lfille%d", i);
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must check the value of `argc` before attempting to use `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`. Here test `if (argc >= 3) {...}` or `if (argc < 3) return 1;`

Comment: the code is supporse to create a chaine of symbolic links given a file name and a number(length of the chain ) as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled the source code with gnu gcc 4.8.2. 
The program worked fine for me. I think you are only passing one argument to the program instead of two. This is why. I suggest what Weather Vane said in his answer.

Comment: could you show me how exactly you passed the argurments?

Comment: If you run your program from a command line: **program_name** **argument1 argument2**. (.i.e suppose our executable file is called _symlin_, and your file is called _link_ and your length of your chaine or whatever is _15_  then: `symlin link 15`

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `*argv[]` is an array of string pointers, with `argc` informing the length of this array.

The first element `argv[0]` points to a string holding the program name. If there were any runtime arguments supplied when the program is run, a string pointer is supplied for each one, with the appropriate value in `argc` to tell you how many elements of the string pointer array have been supplied. If there were no program arguments supplied, `*argv[]` array will have a length of 1.

If you try to access the arguments that *should* have been given, you will be indexing beyond the length of the array `*argv[]` which leads to **undefined behaviour**. You will be dereferencing a pointer which has an essentially *random* value. This might be benign, or it might lead to the **segmentation fault** due to trying to access memory you are not allowed.

I suggest any program which takes (say 2) user arguments at run time have checking code similar to this:

```
if (argc < 3) {
    printf ("Syntax should be: %s filename links\n", argv[0]);
    exit (1);
}
```